# Android Rotate more fluid

Tags: android, rotation, apk, compass-geolocation

I am making a simple compass app for android.
The rotation are okay, but it's laggy.

I have the fallowing code inside the method `onSensorChanged()`:

```
RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(this.currentDegree,
                    -degree, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

            ra.setDuration(0);
            ra.setFillAfter(true);
            this.image.startAnimation(ra);
```

How can I make this more fluid?

Thank you, cumps!